# How do I self-join the result of an aggregate function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have some data in the following format:

```
Table: MountHeights

ID  | Height| Type  |  ItemCode     |  Context
--------------------------------------------
1   | 15    | max   | BD1896-1W     | exterior
2   | 12    | max   | BD1896-1W     | insect
3   | 18    | max   | BD1896-1W     | interior
4   | 13    | max   | BD14120-1W    | exterior
5   | 10    | max   | BD14120-1W    | insect
6   | 15    | max   | BD14120-1W    | interior
```

There are multiple rows for each of the item codes.

I'm trying to figure out a way to get `max(Height)` for each `ItemCode` where the `Type`='max', for some reason, I can't quite wrap my head around how I should reference the table to itself.

I'd like the result to be along the lines of:

```
Results:

 max(Height)| ItemCode  
---------------------------
 18         | BD1896-1W
 15         | BD14120-1W
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to self-reference the table here.

```
SELECT `ItemCode`, MAX( `height` )
FROM `MountHeights`
WHERE `Type`= 'max'
GROUP BY `ItemCode`
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9294cc/1/0)

Comment: That was incredibly fast - Thank you!  I almost had it.  I attempted your query sans the 'GROUP BY' at the end, but since it only returned a single result, I assumed that the GROUP BY wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You want the max height per item code, so you must of course group by item code. Most other dbms would give you a syntax error on the statement, because they request each selected value to be either in the GROUP BY clause or to be aggregated (with MIN, MAX, etc.). This was SQL standard once, but since SQL 99 this has changed; you can have non-grouped, non-aggregated columns as long as they are unique. MySQL allows you to select ItemCode without it being aggregated or grouped by. Unfortunately it doesn't check uniqueness. It should produce an error when both BD1896-1W and BD14120-1W occur.

Comment: That comment was on Zaemz' comment of course. The answer given by Sirko is perfectly fine. I just wanted to explain to Zaemz why it was possible to select ItemCode and get an unexpected result.

Comment: Ah - I see.  To reiterate what you've said to make sure I understand, if I *would not* have included the `GROUP BY` clause using any other DBMS, I would have received an error.

Comment: Yes, correct. It is great that MySQL allows such queries, but it is bad it doesn't check the results. This makes this feature a bit dangerous in MySQL. Always, when you group by and a value is neither in the group by clause nor aggregated, ask yourself if this value will really be unique for the selected set of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
SELECT t1.ItemCode,max(t1.height) as height
from MountHeights as t1, test as t2 
where t1.Type=t2.Type group by t1.Type
```